# How to get an image in a div to completely occupy it Html and CSS?

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

How to get an image in a div to completely occupy it Html and CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place an image as a background like.

html

```
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

css

```
.mydiv {
background-image: img/whatever.jpg;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```